# Slitslider: Pause and play onmouseover

Tags: jquery, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am using the Slitslider slideshow from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/24/slit-slider-revised/

What I like to have is a pause and play function onmouseover / onmouseout. Is this possible? Thank you for any help.

The code is here:

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

    'use strict';

    /*
    * debouncedresize: special jQuery event that happens once after a window resize
    *
    * latest version and complete README available on Github:
    * https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/blob/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js
    *
    * Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
    * Licensed under the MIT license.
    */
    var $event = $.event,
    $special,
    resizeTimeout;

    $special = $event.special.debouncedresize = {
        setup: function() {
            $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler );
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $( this ).off( "resize", $special.handler );
        },
        handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
            // Save the context
            var context = this,
                args = arguments,
                dispatch = function() {
                    // set correct event type
                    event.type = "debouncedresize";
                    $event.dispatch.apply( context, args );
                };

            if ( resizeTimeout ) {
                clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
            }

            execAsap ?
                dispatch() :
                resizeTimeout = setTimeout( dispatch, $special.threshold );
        },
        threshold: 20
    };

    // global
    var $window = $( window ),
        $document = $( document ),
        Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

    $.Slitslider = function( options, element ) {

        this.$elWrapper = $( element );
        this._init( options );

    };

    if(  typeof(Slitslider_options) !== 'undefined' ){
        var slit_autoplay = Slitslider_options.autoplay;
    }else{
        var slit_autoplay = true;
    }

    if( typeof(Slitslider_options) !== 'undefined' ){
        var slit_interval = Slitslider_options.interval;
    }else{
        var slit_interval = 4000;
    }

    $.Slitslider.defaults = {
        // transitions speed
        speed : 80000,
        // if true the item's slices will also animate the opacity value
        optOpacity : false,
        // amount (%) to translate both slices - adjust as necessary
        translateFactor : 230,
        // maximum possible angle
        maxAngle : 25,
        // maximum possible scale
        maxScale : 2,
        // slideshow on / off
        autoplay : slit_autoplay,
        // keyboard navigation
        keyboard : true,
        // time between transitions
        interval : 8000,
        // callbacks
        onBeforeChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; },
        onAfterChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; }
    };

    $.Slitslider.prototype = {

        _init : function( options ) {

            // options
            this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slitslider.defaults, options );

            // https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2870
            this.transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition' : 'transitionend'
            };
            this.transEndEventName = this.transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ];
            // suport for css 3d transforms and css transitions
            this.support = Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
            // the slider
            this.$el = this.$elWrapper.children( '.sl-slider' );
            // the slides
            this.$slides = this.$el.children( '.sl-slide' ).hide();
            // total slides
            this.slidesCount = this.$slides.length;
            // current slide
            this.current = 0;
            // control if it's animating
            this.isAnimating = false;
            // get container size
            this._getSize();
            // layout
            this._layout();
            // load some events
            this._loadEvents();
            // slideshow
            if( this.options.autoplay ) {

                this._startSlideshow();

            }

        },
        // gets the current container width & height
        _getSize : function() {

            this.size = {
                width : this.$elWrapper.outerWidth( true ),
                height : this.$elWrapper.outerHeight( true )
            };

        },
        _layout : function() {

            this.$slideWrapper = $( '<div class="sl-slides-wrapper" />' );

            // wrap the slides
            this.$slides.wrapAll( this.$slideWrapper ).each( function( i ) {

                var $slide = $( this ),
                    // vertical || horizontal
                    orientation = $slide.data( 'orientation' );

                $slide.addClass( 'sl-slide-' + orientation )
                      .children()
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content-wrapper" />' )
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content" />' );

            } );

            // set the right size of the slider/slides for the current window size
            this._setSize();
            // show first slide
            this.$slides.eq( this.current ).show();

        },
        _navigate : function( dir, pos ) {

            if( this.isAnimating || this.slidesCount < 2 ) {

                return false;

            }

            this.isAnimating = true;

            var self = this,
                $currentSlide = this.$slides.eq( this.current );

            // if position is passed
            if( pos !== undefined ) {

                this.current = pos;

            }
            // if not check the boundaries
            else if( dir === 'next' ) {

                this.current = this.current < this.slidesCount - 1 ? ++this.current : 0;

            }
            else if( dir === 'prev' ) {

                this.current = this.current > 0 ? --this.current : this.slidesCount - 1;

            }

            this.options.onBeforeChange( $currentSlide, this.current );

            // next slide to be shown
            var $nextSlide = this.$slides.eq( this.current ),
                // the slide we want to cut and animate
                $movingSlide = ( dir === 'next' ) ? $currentSlide : $nextSlide,

                // the following are the data attrs set for each slide
                configData = $movingSlide.data(),
                config = {};

            config.orientation = configData.orientation || 'horizontal',
            config.slice1angle = configData.slice1Rotation || 0,
            config.slice1scale = configData.slice1Scale || 1,
            config.slice2angle = configData.slice2Rotation || 0,
            config.slice2scale = configData.slice2Scale || 1;

            this._validateValues( config );

            var cssStyle = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                    marginTop : -this.size.height / 2
                } : {
                    marginLeft : -this.size.width / 2
                },
                // default slide's slices style
                resetStyle = {
                    'transform' : 'translate(0%,0%) rotate(0deg) scale(1)',
                    opacity : 1 
                },
                // slice1 style
                slice1Style = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                    'transform' : 'translateY(-' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice1angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice1scale + ')'
                } : {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(-' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice1angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice1scale + ')'
                },
                // slice2 style
                slice2Style = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                    'transform' : 'translateY(' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice2angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice2scale + ')'
                } : {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice2angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice2scale + ')'
                };

            if( this.options.optOpacity ) {

                slice1Style.opacity = 0;
                slice2Style.opacity = 0;

            }

            // we are adding the classes sl-trans-elems and sl-trans-back-elems to the slide that is either coming "next"
            // or going "prev" according to the direction.
            // the idea is to make it more interesting by giving some animations to the respective slide's elements
            //( dir === 'next' ) ? $nextSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-elems' ) : $currentSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-back-elems' );

            $currentSlide.removeClass( 'sl-trans-elems' );

            var transitionProp = {
                'transition' : 'all ' + this.options.speed + 'ms ease-in-out'
            };

            // add the 2 slices and animate them
            $movingSlide.css( 'z-index', this.slidesCount )
                        .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                        .wrap( $( '<div class="sl-content-slice" />' ).css( transitionProp ) )
                        .parent()
                        .cond(
                            dir === 'prev', 
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                this.css( slice1Style );
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    slice.css( resetStyle );

                                }, 50 );

                            }, 
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    slice.css( slice1Style );

                                }, 50 );

                            }
                        )
                        .clone()
                        .appendTo( $movingSlide )
                        .cond(
                            dir === 'prev', 
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                this.css( slice2Style );
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    $currentSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-back-elems' );

                                    if( self.support ) {

                                        slice.css( resetStyle ).on( self.transEndEventName, function() {

                                            self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                        } );

                                    }
                                    else {

                                        self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                    }

                                }, 50 );

                            },
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    $nextSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-elems' );

                                    if( self.support ) {

                                        slice.css( slice2Style ).on( self.transEndEventName, function() {

                                            self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                        } );

                                    }
                                    else {

                                        self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                    }

                                }, 50 );

                            }
                        )
                        .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                        .css( cssStyle );

            $nextSlide.show();

        },
        _validateValues : function( config ) {

            // OK, so we are restricting the angles and scale values here.
            // This is to avoid the slices wrong sides to be shown.
            // you can adjust these values as you wish but make sure you also ajust the
            // paddings of the slides and also the options.translateFactor value and scale data attrs
            if( config.slice1angle > this.options.maxAngle || config.slice1angle < -this.options.maxAngle ) {

                config.slice1angle = this.options.maxAngle;

            }
            if( config.slice2angle > this.options.maxAngle  || config.slice2angle < -this.options.maxAngle ) {

                config.slice2angle = this.options.maxAngle;

            }
            if( config.slice1scale > this.options.maxScale || config.slice1scale <= 0 ) {

                config.slice1scale = this.options.maxScale;

            }
            if( config.slice2scale > this.options.maxScale || config.slice2scale <= 0 ) {

                config.slice2scale = this.options.maxScale;

            }
            if( config.orientation !== 'vertical' && config.orientation !== 'horizontal' ) {

                config.orientation = 'horizontal'

            }

        },
        _onEndNavigate : function( $slice, $oldSlide, dir ) {

            // reset previous slide's style after next slide is shown
            var $slide = $slice.parent(),
                removeClasses = 'sl-trans-elems sl-trans-back-elems';

            // remove second slide's slice
            $slice.remove();
            // unwrap..
            $slide.css( 'z-index', 1 )
                  .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                  .unwrap();

            // hide previous current slide
            $oldSlide.hide().removeClass( removeClasses );
            $slide.removeClass( removeClasses );
            // now we can navigate again..
            this.isAnimating = false;
            this.options.onAfterChange( $slide, this.current );

        },
        _setSize : function() {

            // the slider and content wrappers will have the window's width and height
            var cssStyle = {
                width : this.size.width,
                height : this.size.height
            };

            this.$el.css( cssStyle ).find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' ).css( cssStyle );

        },
        _loadEvents : function() {

            var self = this;

            $window.on( 'debouncedresize.slitslider', function( event ) {

                // update size values
                self._getSize();
                // set the sizes again
                self._setSize();

            } );

            if ( this.options.keyboard ) {

                $document.on( 'keydown.slitslider', function(e) {

                    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
                        arrow = {
                            left: 37,
                            up: 38,
                            right: 39,
                            down: 40
                        };

                    switch (keyCode) {

                        case arrow.left :

                            self._stopSlideshow();
                            self._navigate( 'prev' );
                            break;

                        case arrow.right :

                            self._stopSlideshow();
                            self._navigate( 'next' );
                            break;

                    }

                } );

            }

        },
        _startSlideshow: function() {

            var self = this;

            this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {

                self._navigate( 'next' );

                if ( self.options.autoplay ) {

                    self._startSlideshow();

                }

            }, this.options.interval );

        },
        _stopSlideshow: function() {

            if ( this.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( this.slideshow );
                this.isPlaying = false;
                this.options.autoplay = false;

            }

        },
        _destroy : function( callback ) {

            this.$el.off( '.slitslider' ).removeData( 'slitslider' );
            $window.off( '.slitslider' );
            $document.off( '.slitslider' );
            this.$slides.each( function( i ) {

                var $slide = $( this ),
                    $content = $slide.find( 'div.sl-content' ).children();

                $content.appendTo( $slide );
                $slide.children( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' ).remove();

            } );
            this.$slides.unwrap( this.$slideWrapper ).hide();
            this.$slides.eq( 0 ).show();
            if( callback ) {

                callback.call();

            }

        },
        // public methos: adds more slides to the slider
        add : function( $slides, callback ) {

            this.$slides = this.$slides.add( $slides );

            var self = this;


            $slides.each( function( i ) {

                var $slide = $( this ),
                    // vertical || horizontal
                    orientation = $slide.data( 'orientation' );

                $slide.hide().addClass( 'sl-slide-' + orientation )
                      .children()
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content-wrapper" />' )
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content" />' )
                      .end()
                      .appendTo( self.$el.find( 'div.sl-slides-wrapper' ) );

            } );

            this._setSize();

            this.slidesCount = this.$slides.length;

            if ( callback ) {

                callback.call( $items );

            }

        },
        // public method: shows next slide
        next : function() {

            this._stopSlideshow();
            this._navigate( 'next' );

        },
        // public method: shows previous slide
        previous : function() {

            this._stopSlideshow();
            this._navigate( 'prev' );

        },
        // public method: goes to a specific slide
        jump : function( pos ) {

            pos -= 1;

            if( pos === this.current || pos >= this.slidesCount || pos < 0 ) {

                return false;

            }

            this._stopSlideshow();
            this._navigate( pos > this.current ? 'next' : 'prev', pos );

        },
        // public method: starts the slideshow
        // any call to next(), previous() or jump() will stop the slideshow
        play : function() {

            if( !this.isPlaying ) {

                this.isPlaying = true;

                this._navigate( 'next' );
                this.options.autoplay = true;
                this._startSlideshow();

            }

        },
        // public method: pauses the slideshow
        pause : function() {

            if( this.isPlaying ) {

                this.isPlaying = true;

                this._stopSlideshow();

            }

        },
        // public method: check if isAnimating is true
        isActive : function() {

            return this.isAnimating;

        },
        // publicc methos: destroys the slicebox instance
        destroy : function( callback ) {

            this._destroy( callback );

        }

    };

    var logError = function( message ) {

        if ( window.console ) {

            window.console.error( message );

        }

    };

    $.fn.slitslider = function( options ) {

        var self = $.data( this, 'slitslider' );

        if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

            this.each(function() {

                if ( !self ) {

                    logError( "cannot call methods on slitslider prior to initialization; " +
                    "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                    return;

                }

                if ( !$.isFunction( self[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {

                    logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for slitslider self" );
                    return;

                }

                self[ options ].apply( self, args );

            });

        } 
        else {

            this.each(function() {

                if ( self ) {

                    self._init();

                }
                else {

                    self = $.data( this, 'slitslider', new $.Slitslider( options, this ) );

                }

            });

        }

        return self;

    };

} )( jQuery, window );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you had to wait so long for an answer. I just figured this out after struggling a bit with Slitslider myself.

You shouldn't have to mess with the external slitslider functions. Tweaking the behavior happens where you init the function on your page. Just hook into the play and pause events like so:

```
$(function) {
    var Page = (function() {
    //create a variable for the element you want to trigger pause/play on          
    $slidePause = $('.sl-slide'),
        slitslider = $('#slider').slitslider {
            autoplay:true,
            interval:5000,
            onBeforeChange: function(slide,pos){
                $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
                $nav.eq(pos).addClass('nav-dot-current');
            }
        }),
        init = function() {
            initEvents();
        },
        initEvents = function() {
            // add navigation events
            $navArrows.children(':last').on('click',function(){
                slitslider.next();
                return false;
            });
            $navArrows.children(':first').on('click',function(){
                slitslider.previous();
                return false;
            });
            $nav.each(function(i){
                $(this).on('click',function(event){
                    var $dot = $(this);
                    if (!slitslider.isActive(){
                        $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
                        $dot.addClass('nav-dot-current');
                    }
                    slitslider.jump(i+1);
                    return false;
                });
            });
            // Pause autoplay when mouse enters element
            $slidePause.on('mouseenter',function(){
                slitslider.pause();
            // Resume autoplay when mouse leaves element
            }).on('mouseleave',function(){
                slitslider.play();
            });
        };
        return {init:init};
    })();
    Page.init();
});
```

Works for me. ;)

Comment: thanks, 

does this mean to replace the entire script (from line 107) in the html file (http://pastebin.com/P98ac3U8) with the code you provided?

I did this (see: http://pastebin.com/yuLUAsSx) but it messed up the layout.